# Is it safe to feed a dog bones imported into the USA?

Tags: dogs

I live in the USA and I’ve always heard it was bad to give my dog bones/raw hides produced outside of the country due to the fact that they have to put pesticides on them to get through customs.
Is that still the case if they are wrapped in plastic?

Most of the bones I can find in the store are from China and Columbia, so I was wondering if it's safe to feed them to my dog.

Comment: I am just curious: aren't there enough bones in your country? Whichever country that would be...

Comment: can you add some information about this,like a source for this statement.most of the import/export of animal hides are only refrigated as far as i know.

Answer (score 3):

In USA there is a government organization called "FDA" (from their [website](https://www.fda.gov/animal-veterinary/animal-food-feeds/pet-food)):

> The Food and Drug Administration (FDA) regulates that can of cat food, bag of dog food, or box of dog treats or snacks in your pantry. The FDA’s regulation of pet food is similar to that for other animal foods. The Federal Food, Drug, and Cosmetic Act (FFDCA) requires that all animal foods, like human foods, be safe to eat, produced under sanitary conditions, contain no harmful substances, and be truthfully labeled.

They have a lot of information about the details on their website, for example labels they regulate. These labels show you, if the imported bones are "good" in USA standards.

In my opinion, you should not judge all imported products with one assumption. But like virolino wrote, there are risks in general if you choose the wrong bones (too hard, prone to splintering, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what industries will tell you, not everything that is sold in stores is suitable for your pet (this is valid for cats also, with their respective specificities).

Food that is too tough will possibly hurt his gums, and maybe even break his teeth. If the bone breaks "improperly", it might scratch his digestive tract, which will lead to infections and further trouble.

There are countless articles on the net written WITHOUT sponsorship, all of them bringing testimony against tough toys and tough food. The bones and the muscles used in chewing were made for food, not for crushing stones.

You must be aware that even bones which are not tough, are able to hurt the dog. Especially: big bird-bones (they splinter) and fish bones.

Note: all cooked / boiled bones are unsuitable to be chewed by pets - they are too tough.

You can successfully feed small bird-bones (phalanges, chest, head / neck), the (soft) endings of bigger bones etc.

---

> outside of the country ... they have to put pesticides ...

Are you claiming that USA is pesticide free? They are already in everything we eat, regardless of the country, especially when talking about "civilized" countries. We = animals, birds, humans...

Bonus info: pesticides are only a part of the problem. There are also hormones, medicine, heavy metals, additives ...

So from this point of view, domestic or imported products, it is the same.

---

Question to self: aren't pesticides used only in agriculture, to kill the insects which damage crops?

Comment: If the "question to self" is ironic, I did not get it ;) No the pesticides are not only in agriculture, they were feed with the crops to "meat-animals" and with the meat they come to the "kitchen"

Comment: I did not refer to the presence of pesticides (unfortunately, they end up everywhere), I referred to where they are used directly. The question implies that the bones are treated specifically with pesticides - which I find unlikely. Maybe it is partially ironic - but I am no expert to know exactly who, how and where actually uses pesticides - so it is a real question also.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Maybe the OP has sorrow, the bones become a treatment for the transport with substances against "eaten by insects in over seas container"

Comment: I understand your point. However, I only commented on what is specifically written in the question. If OP wants other information, he / she is welcome to ask.

Comment: Answer to the question to self: no, insecticides are only [one of the many kinds of pesticides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesticide). Pesticide is anything that kills or stops from growing or deters/repells anything we deem to be a pest.